# How to disable source control in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to see any of this circles and numbers.

[image: screenshot]

By the way, `git.enabled`, `git.decorations.enabled`, `git.autoRepositoryDetection` are `false`.

Comment: this has nothing to do with git, it is a marking that the file is not-saved (circle) and how many errors there are in the file, SCM markings are `M` and `U`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `git.decorations.enabled`, try setting `explorer.decorations.badges` and `explorer.decorations.colors` to `false`.

Comment: My fault, I didn't realize this is not not commited changes, but warnings.